# EXCEL VBA: Copy Rows from Sheet A to end of Sheet B

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Copy rows from Sheet A to the end of Sheet B which already has a list of data in it. I used the code shown below. The problem is every time I try to run this particular code the whole program crashes.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1  


    For j = 1 To 50
        On Error GoTo Err_Execute
        Sheets("A").Rows(j).Copy
        Sheets("B").Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        i = i + 1
    Next j

Err_Execute:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows are you trying to copy?

Comment: 50 rows right now. I might have to copy around 500 later on.

Comment: You should change i = Activesheet.range to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet B").Range

Comment: And also why insert them, and not paste, as you are first calculating the last row.

Comment: My answer should work for any amount of rows, @Luuklag I had the same thought, built paste into below

Comment: Just a quick thing to be aware of when referencing row numbers in Excel; depending how large the dataset gets, you may find you need to set the data type as Long otherwise as soon as i or j reach a value greater than 32767 you will get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below works. I have added a lastrow for sheet A just so that it is slightly more dynamic. I have moved on error too, you dont need to set this every loop only at the beginning

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Last_row as Integer

i = Sheets("B").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
last_row = Sheets("A").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

On Error GoTo Err_Execute
For j = 1 To last_row
    Sheets("A").Rows(j).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("B").Rows(i).PasteSpecial
    i = i + 1
Next j

Err_Execute:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Actually why are you looping at all? The below just selects all the rows and copies them in one action. Should be much quicker

```
Sub test()
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
With Sheets("A")
    .Rows("1:" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).EntireRow.Copy
End With
With Sheets("B")
    .Rows(.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial
End With

Err_Execute:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I have posted a second solution which should be much quicker. If this has solved your problem please mark it as answered (the little grey tick to the left of my answer)